# Chaining Controller Actions and/or promises in 1 button click

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I currently have my project working about 75% of the time, I create report/reports add them to a zip, unzip them to a certain location. When I run this in debug mode it works correctly. When i run it normally sometimes the ajax will run out of order and it will try to unzip the file before its zipped (nothing is there). I have been doing trial and error with this trying many different methods to get this to work.

I tried multiple ways to do this: with the success: of ajax. I tried a .done promise after ajax. I tried a bool : if statement I tried many different conditions. It seems to finally be working in the correct order when i first open the project and select the records and the button click. Only 1 time it will do it successful. 
When I try to select new records and run it a 2nd time the unzip folder isnt always created Or if it'll be created but will be empty (No reports unzipped to it).

Here is what I currently have which sometime works. Once I have this going good then I have to create the last step which will be to create an email and attach the document.

```
if (isValid) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Service/ExportFiles/",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { "quoteIDs" : arrSelectedChks },
                    success: function () {
                        window.location = '/Service/DownloadAsZip/';
                        // DownloadAsZip?mimeType=' + data;
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert("Error Generating Files");
                        //+ request.responseText);
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Service/UnZipDownload",
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (response) {
                            //alert("success in unzip");
                            CallEmail();
                        }
                    })
                });
```

Here is another way i been doing this.

```
if (isValid) { /* At least 1 record is selected */
                var phaseOne = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    url: "/Service/ExportFiles/",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { "quoteIDs": arrSelectedChks },

                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location = '/Service/DownloadAsZip';
                        successful = true
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        if (successful)
                            isZipped = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            $.when(phaseOne).always(function () {
                if (isZipped) { /* Files are Zipped to start this phase */
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "/Service/UnZipDocument",
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        traditional: true,

                    });
                }
            })
```

P.S. I have both Controller Actions UnZipDownload and UnZipDocument (both similar) if needing to see the action i will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried SO MANY DIFFERENT results to try to get this to work with the click of 1 button. BUT the only way I have found out a way to get this to work is to have 1 button to do the report creating and zipping of the files. Then to have a second button (mines currently in a modal) and on this button click I am unzipping the file and creating the email. I have not been able to do everything all in 1 call. When I try my unzip functions is being called before my zip function I have tried many different ways to try to not have this happen [success, .done(), deferred objects, javascript promises]

```
$('#btnGetChkEmail').on('click', function() {
            var arrChkBoxes = [];
            var arrSelectedChks = [];
            var myJSON = {};
            var phaseOne, phaseTwo;
            var isValid = false;
            var bool = false;
            var isZipped = false;
            //var unZipped = false;
            var successful = false;

            // Turn all selected checkbox T/F values into QuoteIDs
            $("input:checked").each(function (index, value) {
                arrChkBoxes.push($(value).val());
            });
            // Push all Selected QIDs on NEW ARRAY
            $.each(arrChkBoxes, function (key, value) {
                if (IsPositiveInteger(value)) {
                    arrSelectedChks.push(value);
                }
            });

            if (arrSelectedChks.length === 0) { // Create Modal (Error ~ None ~ Selected)
                isValid = false;
                alert("No Records Selected");
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }

        /* EDITION LIKE GETCHKS */
            if (isValid) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Service/ExportFiles/",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { "quoteIDs": arrSelectedChks },
                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location = '/Service/DownloadAsZip';
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert("Error Generating Reports");
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    /* Only way to do this 100% at the moment is to bring up a Button in a Modal */
                    var zipModal = $("#zipModEmail");
                    var modalHead = "<h3 class='modal-title'>Generate Email Messages</h3>";
                    var modalBody = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' style='font-size:5em; color:green;'></span>" +
                        "<p><b>Attach PDF's to email Confirmation</b></p>" +
                        "<p>Click 'OK' to Confirm</p>";
                    //var modalFoot = "";
                    zipModal.find(".modal-header").html(modalHead);
                    zipModal.find(".modal-header").addClass("alert-success");
                    zipModal.find(".modal-body").html(modalBody);
                    zipModal.modal("show");
                });
            }
$("#btnUnNemail").click(function (e) {
            var myJSON = {};
            var bool = false;

            var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Service/UnZipDocument",
                            data: {},
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (response) {
                                debugger;
                                if (response.Status == "Unzipped") {
                                    myJSON = { "Status": "Unzipped", "FilePath": response.FilePath, "FileName": response.FileName, "FileNames": response.FileNames };
                                    bool = true;
                                }
                                $("#zipModEmail").modal("hide");

                            }
                        });

            // Try switching to 'POST'
            $.when(ajaxCall).then(function () {
                if (bool) {
                    //debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("CreateEmailReport", "Service")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                        data: { "folderData": myJSON },
                        traditional: true,
                    })
                }
            });          
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your the second function only if the first is successful

```
if (isValid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Service/ExportFiles/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            data: { "quoteIDs" : arrSelectedChks }
        }).done(function(){
             window.location = '/Service/DownloadAsZip/';
                // DownloadAsZip?mimeType=' + data;
                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Service/UnZipDownload",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }).done(function(){
                 //alert("success in unzip");
                    CallEmail();
            });
        }).fail(function(){
             alert("Error Generating Files");
                //+ request.responseText);
        });
```

Comment: even with this the same thing happens. The unzip runs before the zip. i just tried it exactly like this.. not to sure why..

Comment: Try the updated code, success was replaced by done, error by fail

Comment: nope.. same the the unzip happens b4 the zip somehow

Comment: can you share an app on github? its easy for me to correct it

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/henxNu    Thats all the code for MVC of what you should need